# SCSS Margin-top Not working unless inside nested class

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am working on a prototype that is styled using `SCSS`. For some reason, when I put the `margin-top: 0;` on the parent element, it is not taking effect. When I put the `margin-top` inside the nested classes, it works. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Here is the full code snippet that doesn't work how it is intended:

```
.form__row{
 margin-top: 0;

 &__error-message{
  color: $color--negative;
 }

 &__success-message{
  color: $success-body-text;
 }

 &__attention-message{
  color: $attention-body-text;
 }

 &__info-message{
  color: $info-body-text;
 }
}
```

Here is the code snippet that works but is poor design:

```
.form__row{

 &__error-message{
  color: $color--negative;
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 &__success-message{
  color: $success-body-text;
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 &__attention-message{
  color: $attention-body-text;
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 &__info-message{
  color: $info-body-text;
  margin-top: 0;
 }
}
```

Lastly, here is the HTML as rendered:

```
<div class="detail-group__row ">
 <p class="form__row__success-message">
   <span class="icon-check small" aria-hidden="true"></span>

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecutir.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: does form__row have a margin? afaik margin isnt inherited

Comment: @ChrisLi, `<p>` does and `.form__row` is a class off of p tags

Comment: Edit your post and add your HTML structure.

Comment: @QuentinVéron done

Comment: The p has a margin of its own. Setting the margin of its parent to 0 does not change that fact.

Comment: @MrLister so should I specify the selector p.forn__row?

Comment: You don't have any 'form__row' class in your HTML

Comment: @EliTownsend That depends on what you want to achieve. If you only want to write `margin-top:0;` in one spot, then `.detail-group__row > *:first-child {margin-top:0;}` will do the trick. Also see Quentin's comment.

Comment: @MrLister I will give that a shot. Also there is not a specific class of `form__row` but with the nesting element of SASS, the class becomes `form__row__success-message`

Comment: @EliTownsend Yes, but in your question, you start out with `.form__row{
 margin-top: 0;` which does not do anything.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I understand now